# /etc/X11/xorg.conf reset at each boot

Tags: centos, x11, xorg, nvidia, gpu

I have a bunch of Centos workstations with different Nvidia cards. 
In the `nvidia-settings` interface, I need to enable this option: **Force Full Composition Pipeline**.

This is then saved to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. It appears like this in the file:

```
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, DP-0.8: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
```

The issue I have is that at each boot, my `xorg.conf` file is reset containing only:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Videocard0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
EndSection
```

Is it normal that this file is reset at each boot? 
How can I disable this function and be sure that the option is enabled at each boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this script at startup:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="$(nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode -t|tr '\n' ' '|sed -e 's/.*:: \(.*\)/\1\n/g' -e 's/}/, ForceCompositionPipeline = On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}/g')" > /dev/null
```

If you want it to be executed on startup, you can drop those lines in an executable file in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/

Eg: /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/99-force-composition-pipeline